# Remove newline ? using awk?

Tags: linux, awk

I have text below:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 502      136       2607104 Dec 15 11:05 YUH985335
-rw-r--r--    1 502      136       2433024 Dec 15 11:06 YUH985336
```

I want to result become like this

```
15-Dec-2016_11:05 YUH985335 2607104
15-Dec-2016_11:06 YUH985336 2433024
```

I have try this code

```
awk -v year=${year} {print $7"-"$6"-"year"_"$8,  $9,  $5}
```

but the result have new line in middle

```
15-Dec-2016_11:05 YUH985335 
2607104
15-Dec-2016_11:06 YUH985336 
2433024
```

how to remove newline at column `$9` in awk?

Comment: Are you sure that is the exact code (for example, it's missing `'`s)? There is no `RS` set somewhere or something, just `RS` wouldn't cause that? You could try `sub(/\n/,"",$9)`.

Comment: You shouldnt try and parse ls

Comment: How about `ls -l --time-style=+%d-%b-%Y_%H:%M`?

Comment: Use `printf` with format spicifiers instead

Comment: Does your actual code quote the awk script (i.e., `'{ print $7… }'`? If yes, then it works fine for me with your example input. (In any case, make sure you show us the _exact_ code you are running.)

Comment: Your input file contains control Ms remove them using dos2unix or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dwi Yanuar: Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk -v year=${year} '{printf("%d-%s-%d_%d %d %d\n",$7,$6,year,$8,$9,$5)}'  Input_file
```